# how to make conditions for datetime and time in javascript postman test?

Tags: javascript, postman

I'm doing tests for the following code,
i need to create a conditions ( if )  for the following variables:

```
"date" : "rdvPrestationHoraireDate",
"heure" : "rdvPrestationHoraireHeure",
"heureDebut" : "rdvPrestationHoraireHeureDebut",
"heureFin" : "rdvPrestationHoraireHeureFin", `
```

- the duration of the appointment does not exceed "rdvPrestationDuree" does not exceed 60 minutes
- that the appointment can be priced only 1 day before
- that the start time of the start time"dateDebut" appointment is not greater than the end date of the end time"dateFin" appointment

More details:

```html
pm.environment.set("rdvPrestationId", "");
pm.environment.set("rdvPrestationHoraireName", "HoraireFixe");
pm.environment.set("rdvPrestationHoraireDate", "{{aPartirDuLendemain}}");
pm.environment.set("rdvPrestationTypeName", "Telephonique");
pm.environment.set("rdvPrestationNomIntervenant", "STARK");
pm.environment.set("rdvPrestationPrenomIntervenant", "Tony");
pm.environment.set("rdvPrestationTelephoneIntervenant", "0549010203");
pm.environment.set("rdvPrestationReferenceIntervenant", "IM1234");
pm.environment.set("RdvMotifModificationName", "");
pm.environment.set("rdvPrestationNotes", "Notes pris pour rendez vous");
pm.environment.set("rdvPrestationDuree", "60");


var exempleFlux = {

    "prestationId" : "rdvPrestationId",
    "horaire" : {
        "name" : "rdvPrestationHoraireName",
        "value" : { 
            "date" : "rdvPrestationHoraireDate",
            "heure" : "rdvPrestationHoraireHeure",
            "heureDebut" : "rdvPrestationHoraireHeureDebut",
            "heureFin" : "rdvPrestationHoraireHeureFin", 
        },
        "label" : "",
    },
    "dureeRendezVous" : "rdvPrestationDuree",        
    "notes" : "rdvPrestationNotes",
    "typeRendezVous" : {
        "name" : "rdvPrestationTypeName"
    },
    "MotifModificationRdv":{
        "name": "RdvMotifModificationName"
        } ,
    "nomIntervenant" : "rdvPrestationNomIntervenant",
    "prenomIntervenant" : "rdvPrestationPrenomIntervenant",
    "telephoneIntervenant" : "rdvPrestationTelephoneIntervenant",
    "referenceIntervenant" : "rdvPrestationReferenceIntervenant",
}
```

Comment: Please post code instead of images of code

Comment: Sorry i just start to use this account i don't know how to edit i can't find it

Comment: Under your post: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54007335/edit

Comment: I did it :) thank you very much

Comment: I reformatted and removed the now unnecessary image